# Autonumbering is not working on added rows

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 functions. Add dynamic rows and Autonumbering. My problem is, my autonumbering is not working on my dynamically added rows. I wonder what could be the problem? The "class="form-control" is all the same for my input type field. However, it is still not working. I have provided my js fiddle below.

https://prnt.sc/124vuju

https://jsfiddle.net/rain0221/59k4c0yg/3/ // in "lb" column, type any number and hit ctrl+enter in order to do autonumbering

```js
//this is my function for autonumbering
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");

inputs[0].addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  let value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 10)) {
    inputs.forEach((inp, i) => {
      if (i !== 0) {
        inp.value = ++value;
      }
    })
  }
})

//this is my function for adding dynamic rows.

$("#addrow").on('click', function() {

  let rowIndex = $('.auto_num').length + 1;
  let rowIndexx = $('.auto_num').length + 1;

  var newRow = '<tr><td><input class="auto_num"  type="text" value="' + rowIndexx + '" /></td>"' +
    '<td><input name="lightBand' + rowIndex + '" id="auto"  value="" class="form-control"  type="number" readonly /></td>"' +
    '<td><input id="weight' + rowIndex + '" name="weight' + rowIndex + '" type="number" /></td>"' +
    '<td><input id="wingBand' + rowIndex + '" name="wingBand' + rowIndex + '" type="number" /></td>"' +
    '<td><input type="button" class="removerow" id="removerow' + rowIndex + '" name="removerow' + rowIndex + '" value="Remove"/></td>';

  $("#applicanttable > tbody > tr:last").after(newRow);


});

$(document).on('click', '.removerow', function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  regenerate_auto_num();
});

function regenerate_auto_num() {
  let count = 1;
  $(".auto_num").each(function(i, v) {
    $(this).val(count);
    count++;
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" border="1" id="applicanttable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <div class="row">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>LB#</th>
        <th>Weight#</th>
        <th>Wingband #</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row_0">
        <td>
          <input id="#" name="#" class="auto_num" type="text" value="1" readonly />
        </td>
        <td class="labelcell">
          <input value="" class="hehe form-control" placeholder="" required id="auto" />
        </td>
        <td class="labelcell">
          <input name="weight" class="hehe form-control" type="number" />
        </td>
        <td class="labelcell">
          <input name="wingBand" class="hehe form-control" type="number" />
        </td>
        <td class="labelcell">
          <input type="button" class="removerow" id="removerow0" name="removerow0" value="Remove">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </tbody>
  </div>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <button type="button" id="addrow" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Add Row</button>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: You can't have a `<div>` directly inside `<tbody>`, that's invalid markup. `<tr>` already stands for `table row`

Comment: the added row is on `readonly`, does it give a randomize number when you click the `add row` button?

Comment: Hello, even it's not readonly, it is not working. It does not giving randomize number either. 

Here's the screenshot for my target: https://prnt.sc/124vuju

Comment: what i mean is, if you click the `add row button` does it automatically gives a random number to the LB?

Comment: Your code has many more problems than you are asking here. Check my answer below for an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the elements inside eventListener event. Since you are finding the element global onload so if will not hold the elements added dynamically. You can move the blow code inside addEventListener keyup event.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");
```

To attach the keyup event, you can use `document.querySelectorAll(".form-control")[0]` instead of `inputs[0]`.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".form-control")[0].addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");
    let value = parseInt(e.target.value);
    if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 10)) {
      inputs.forEach((inp, i) => {
        if (i !== 0) {
          inp.value = ++value;
        }
      })
    }
  });
```

I can see that you have assigned the 'form-control' class only for LB# column so autonumber will be generate only for LB#. In case you want to generate autonumber for all the columns, assign the class="form-control" to each  added dynamically.

Comment: Wow, perfectly working. Will definitely study about that. Thank you so much,

Comment: This still doesn't add a `keyup` listener to the dynamically added rows.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".form-control")[0]` in result identical to `document.querySelector(".form-control")`.

Comment: Yes. keyup event is attached to LB# for the first row. LB# is readonly for dynamically added row.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are addding `keyup` listeners **only to those elements that are already present in the DOM at the time you are adding them.**

What you need instead is called **delegate listeners**, and it means that you rely on the mechanism that most **events bubble up** in the DOM, allowing you to attach the `keyup` listener to an element that is an ancestor to all the `input` elements of interest.

Inside that listener, you then check if the element they event came from is one you want to handle.

```js
//this is my function for autonumbering
const inputAncestor = document.querySelector("tbody");

inputAncestor.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if (
    e.target.matches('input.form-control') &&
    ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 10))
  ) {
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");
    let value = parseInt(e.target.value);
    inputs.forEach((inp) => {
      if (inp !== e.target) {
        inp.value = ++value;
      }
    })
  }
})

//this is my function for adding dynamic rows.

$("#addrow").on('click', function() {

  let rowIndex = $('.auto_num').length + 1;
  let rowIndexx = $('.auto_num').length + 1;

  var newRow = '<tr><td><input class="auto_num"  type="text" value="' + rowIndexx + '" /></td>"' +
    '<td><input name="lightBand' + rowIndex + '" value="" class="form-control"  type="number" readonly /></td>"' +
    '<td><input id="weight' + rowIndex + '" name="weight' + rowIndex + '" type="number" /></td>"' +
    '<td><input id="wingBand' + rowIndex + '" name="wingBand' + rowIndex + '" type="number" /></td>"' +
    '<td><input type="button" class="removerow" id="removerow' + rowIndex + '" name="removerow' + rowIndex + '" value="Remove"/></td>';

  $("#applicanttable > tbody > tr:last").after(newRow);
});

$(document).on('click', '.removerow', function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  regenerate_auto_num();
});

function regenerate_auto_num() {
  let count = 1;
  $(".auto_num").each(function(i, v) {
    $(this).val(count);
    count++;
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" border="1" id="applicanttable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>LB#</th>
      <th>Weight#</th>
      <th>Wingband #</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row_0">
      <td>
        <input id="#" name="#" class="auto_num" type="text" value="1" readonly />
      </td>
      <td class="labelcell">
        <input value="" class="hehe form-control" placeholder="" required id="auto" />
      </td>
      <td class="labelcell">
        <input name="weight" class="hehe form-control" type="number" />
      </td>
      <td class="labelcell">
        <input name="wingBand" class="hehe form-control" type="number" />
      </td>
      <td class="labelcell">
        <input type="button" class="removerow" id="removerow0" name="removerow0" value="Remove">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=5><button type="button" id="addrow" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Add Row</button>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, your code has several more problems, which I tried to fix.

1. As mentioned in the first comment to your question, you cannot have a `div` as a child of  `tbody`. Only `tr` is allowed here.
2. You are using duplicate id value `auto`. That is invalid HTML.
3. In your markup, you have the class `form-control` on all the inputs. In your dynamically added markup it's only on the first input. Which version is the correct one?
4. In your `tfoot` you had the `button` as direct child. This is, *again*, invalid HTML. The only child element(s) `tfoot` can have is `tr`.
5. The very first row in your table describes the columns and acts as your table's header, yet it did not reside in the `thead` part of your table.